# Fix 'new enumerations must be created as'

Tags: python, python-2.7, enums, typeerror

I'm working in Python 2 and have the following class

```
import enum

class MyClass(object):
    pass

@enum.unique
classMyEnum(enum.IntEnum, MyClass):
    A = 1
    B = 2
```

When I run this code I get a following error:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\enum\__init__.py", line 506, in _get_mixins_
    raise TypeError("new enumerations must be created as "
TypeError: new enumerations must be created as `ClassName([mixin_type,] enum_type)`
```

I work with Python on a regular basis but I must admit I never really dove into it. I can't really figure out what is going on. I'm not really sure how to read this error. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: In your code sample you are missing a space in `class MyEnum`

Answer (score 9):

The error is because you need to list the `MixinType` before your `Enum` class, like:

```
class FunEnum(int, Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
```

But since you're already using `intEnum` (which is already a mixed enum) you don't want mix in another type, right? So you can simply use:

```
@enum.unique
class FunEnum(enum.IntEnum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
```

The mixin type defines to which class the values are converted and how could Python resolve this if you want `MyClass` and `int`? Therefore attempthing it throws another error:

```
@enum.unique
class FunEnum(str, enum.IntEnum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
```

> TypeError: multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict

or

```
class MyClass(object):
    pass

@enum.unique
class FunEnum(MyClass, enum.IntEnum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
```

> TypeError: `object.__new__(FunEnum)` is not safe, use `int.__new__()`

Comment: Actually, mixing `MyClass` and `int` with `Enum` seems to work fine, if you order the inheritance correctly. `class MyEnum(int, MyClass, enum.Enum):` works just fine, because it ensures that `int.__new__` takes precedence over the generic (and inappropriate for an `int` subclass) `object.__new__`. You just have to explicitly put `int` ahead of the other super classes, which means you have to inherit from `int` and `enum.Enum` separately (this is fine though; `IntEnum` itself is an empty class defined as `class IntEnum(int, Enum):`).

Comment: hm, interesting point. I never assumed that would make sense given that they override each others `__new__`.

Comment: `__new__` is subject to normal lookup rules for inheritance; you find the first class in the MRO with an implementation and call it. Any further delegation is up to that method; if it doesn't delegate further, no other `__new__`s are invoked. This does mean that if `MyClass` needs initialization, you'd need to put it in `__init__` (which `int` doesn't interfere with) or put it first in the list of bases and overload `__new__` explicitly such that it delegates to `super().__new__` and then initializes the result further. I didn't say it wasn't complicated. :-)